# Using other boards than PCB for commercial electronics products

Tags: pcb, production

If one solders entire circuit components (such as resistors, caps, opamps) a board as in the following photo:

[image]

Is this type of interfacing legal for commercial products? I'm wondering if there is any restrictions to use only PCB for commercial product and CE marking.

(Of course all electronics assumed to be inside an enclosure)

Comment: can you make sure the components will stay in place, all the connections will be firm and no components will unintentionally touch each other over the lifetime of the product (including someone carelessly tossing the thing into the bag)? Also, you need to make sure all signals are within acceptable noisiness levels, and there is also an emission factor to take into account, these breadboards are not great at both of these parameters. Are you sure you can solve all these matters to begin with?

Comment: Legal according to what law? Generally, everything is legal unless there's a reason it would be illegal. What is the reason you think this might be illegal? Consumer protection laws because of low quality or low safety, maybe?

Comment: Have you seen how old *commercial* electronics were built? Before the days of *printed* circuit boards?

Comment: What voltage are we talking about? Mains connected?

Comment: Electronics are usually certified by different standards which are chosen based on the intended end-user. As long as you are claiming a certain standard compliance and actually complying it, it is legal.

Comment: Having a proper PCB manufactured is WAY WAY cheaper than you think it is.   Don't mess around with hobby stuff for a commercial product, even if it's low production numbers.  The board you have in your hand is for you to make one prototype from - It's not meant for commercial products.

Answer (score 5):

That is as much a PCB than any other PCB is. Nothing illegal with the PCB itself.

Safety and legal issues affect you whether you use that board or design a custom PCB. If the product does not adhere to safety regulations then it will be unsafe and you have legal responsibility.

If you use that board for mains voltage for example and don't make sure it passes all safety rule checks, then it is not safe. Since these boards will likely be hand-made to cut tracks and solder components, it might be hard to make sure each and all boards are within margins of safety limits.

So that might be fine for a couple of prototypes, but given how easily you can design a custom PCB and how cheaply they can be manufactured, it might even be cheaper to order ready made boards with components mounted on it, than to use time to solder components to veroboard. And it looks more professional. It might even allow to use smaller and cheaper surface mount components that will make the product smaller and easier to manufacture with less manual labour and make a product that weighs less.